# How to quickly find out the changelist deleting a line

Tags: perforce

I need to find out which changelist deleted a particular line from a file. This file is regularly updated by many people. I have 2 changelist at hand, one has the line and the other does not. The problem is, there are numerous changes in between.

Any pointer is appreciated!

[UPDATE]
I found this script, http://projects.joelinoff.com/p4tools/p4-whodunit.py, but it does not work for me:

```
$~/tmp/p4-whodunit.py  --help
: No such file or directory

$~/tmp/p4-whodunit.py  //depot/mybranch/file1
: No such file or directory
```

Not familiar with python, not sure what to do with it.

Comment: The raw material for answering your query is in `p4 annotate //depot/mybranch/file1@c1,c2`, where `c1` and `c2` are the changelists in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "p4 annotate -a" to find out when the line was last present; the following revision is the one that removed it.

In this example, line A was added in revision 2, and removed (replaced by B) in revision 3:

```
C:\test\local\dvcs\i\deltas>p4 annotate -a foo
//stream/main/i/deltas/foo#3 - edit change 50625 (text)
1-1: 1:
2-2: 1: A
3-3: 1: B
```

So to answer the question of "in what changelist did line A get deleted?" I can do:

```
C:\test\local\dvcs\i\deltas>p4 annotate -a foo | grep A
2-2: 1: A

C:\test\local\dvcs\i\deltas>p4 files foo#3
//stream/main/i/deltas/foo#3 - edit change 50625 (text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use P4V's Timelapse View. It will show the changelist that added the line, and the changelist that deleted the line.